# How do you send notifications based on user input? SWIFT

Tags: swift, notifications

1. How do you set the notification time to match the input of the user?
2. If a notification reminds the user of new content (i.e the word of the day), is that considered a local notification or a push notification?

The `userSelectedTime` variable is created when they press done, but I don't know how to pass it on to my `sendNotification` function which uses DateComponents() to set the time.

```
@objc func donePressed() {
        // formatter
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .none
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
                
        var userSelectedTime = timeTextField.text
        userSelectedTime = formatter.string(from: timePicker.date)
        print(userSelectedTime)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

func sendNotification() {
    
    // Default time 10:30, but base it on userSelectedTime if not void
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 10
        dateComponents.minute = 30
    
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: createNotificationContent(for: myData), trigger: trigger)
    
        center.add(request)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will answer your question 2. - This mostly depends on where that information is coming from. If the "word of the day" is something you have stored internally inside the app, you can schedule a local notification with that information. However, if you want to change the word of the day externally every day, you will have to create a push notification to achieve this. (At least the only way to make it work properly). Push notifications would require some sort of service to push those to the app so the easiest for you is to go with the local notifications.

**To summarize question 2:**

*Local notification:* Something that is created within the app.
*Push notification:* Information 'pushed' from an external source.

**Question 1:**

You can do this in a number of ways. What I would recommend from looking at what you already have is to create the date components with the selected time and pass those components to your 'sendNotification()' function.

As an example:

```
// Capture the time and turn them into components
func donePressed() {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .month, .year, .day], from: timePicker.date)
    sendNotification(components: components)
}

// Schedule the notificaiton based on components
func sendNotification(components: DateComponents) {
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: createNotificationContent(for: myData), trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
}
```

Now... I can't see all your code, so I assume that what else you got going is working properly. But I hope you get the concept. I would however recommend creating a separate class like "NotificationScheduler" to handle these things, that way you will be able to separate things a bit more.

Comment: Thank you Björn! In regards to question 2: The file for my practice app "word of the day" is all within the Xcode project, and supposed to be fired off every 24 hours (still not sure how I will implement this though). 

I suppose this would require a local notification, but I want the user to be alerted that new data is available (I.e the new word for the day) without relying on whether they opened the app or not, but that would make it a push notification?

Comment: If you have all the "Word of the day" in the app, like in a JSON file or simply as a giant Array, and you want to push them every day at a specific time. What you will have to do is the first time the user opens the app and schedules these notifications (like I want them every day at 08:00) you can schedule all the notifications for the next 365+ days. So you simply make a loop that creates 1 non-repeating notification for each day at 08:00 with a quote. Otherwise, yes you would need to work with push notifications :)

Comment: Thank you again Björn! Issue 1 is now all good as I am able to set the notification time to the userSelectedTime. Thanks again!